# RxJava, Retrofit, Android - wait untill all requests finish

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a method to ping all computers on a list called `computerItemList` and check if it's online or not. I want to do it by sending parallel requests to API. Code below simulates response from server and it is working but I need information when all requests finish unblocking ping button. How to do that?
Generally, I want to execute async command on all items on list and then wait until all finish.

```
public void pingComputers() {
        for (ComputerItem computerItem : _computerItemList) {
            Observable.just(computerItem)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(item -> {
                        int sleepTime = randomizer.nextInt(1000) + 200;
                        int status = randomizer.nextInt(ComputerStatus.values().length - 1) + 1;

                        Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName() + " >>pingSelected: " + item + " sleep: " + sleepTime);
                        Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                        item.setStatus(ComputerStatus.values()[status]);

                        updateComputerList();
                    });
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
I wrote something like this. Is it okay?

```
public void ping2() {
        Observable.fromIterable(_computerItemList)
                .flatMap(computerItem -> {
                    return Observable.just(computerItem)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .map(item -> {
                                int sleepTime = randomizer.nextInt(1000) + 200;
                                Log.d(TAG, "ping2: Sleeping for " + sleepTime);
                                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);

                                int status = randomizer.nextInt(ComputerStatus.values().length - 1) + 1;
                                item.setStatus(ComputerStatus.values()[status]);

                                updateComputerList();
                                return item;
                            });
                }).doOnComplete(() -> Log.d(TAG, "ping2: COMPLETE")).subscribe();

    }
```

**UPDATE - IT IS WORKING! But is it okay???**

```
public void executeCommand(CommandType command) {
        isWorking.setValue(true);
        
        Observable.fromIterable(_computerItemList)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMap(computerItem -> createPingObservable(computerItem))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnComplete(() -> isWorking.setValue(false))
                .subscribe();
    }


private Observable<ComputerItem> createPingObservable(ComputerItem computerItem) {
        return Observable.just(computerItem)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(item -> {
                    int sleepTime = randomizer.nextInt(1000) + 200;
                    int status = randomizer.nextInt(ComputerStatus.values().length - 1) + 1;

                    Log.d(TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName() + ">>> executeCommand: PING");
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                    item.setStatus(ComputerStatus.values()[status]);

                    updateComputerList();
                    return item;
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE - IT IS WORKING! But is it okay???

No, it's not ok to call `updateComputerList();` that way, you would have to `synchronized` it because you will be calling it from multiple threads, each of them trying to mutate the state.

I would do it this way:

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
                    .flatMap(computerItem -> createPingObservable(computerItem))
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(computerItem -> updateComputerList(computerItem));
        }
```

Also, don't use `Thread.sleep(sleepTime);`, just use

`.delay(randomizer.nextInt(1000) + 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

Comment: I know, but I want to update the list every time a response comes from the API server. Basically when the ping button is clicked I want to send requests to the server for all computers on list and when response comes I want to update its state.